# An unexpected file id was encountered. File id 15 was expected but 14 was read from "..."

Tags: sql-server, database

Please help!

I restarted a server where SQL SERVER 2012 is running on this morning. After the server was back, I found one user database were in "Recovery Pending" status in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

In SQL log, I found the error msg:

Error: 5161, Severity: 16, State: 1.

An unexpected file id was encountered. File id 15 was expected but 14 was read from "\SQL-Server\DATA\15 Thumbdrive\DB\0014_TSf.ndf". Verify that files are mapped correctly in sys.master_files. ALTER DATABASE can be used to correct the mappings.

Error: 5105, Severity: 16, State: 1.

A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\SQL-Server\DATA\15 Thumbdrive\DB\0014_TSf.ndf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

I checked in sys.master_files, and got results as below:

```
database_id  file_id  name        physical_name
5            14       0013_TSf    \\SQL-Server\DATA\Test_\DB\0013_TSf.ndf
5            15       0014_TSf    \\SQL-Server\DATA\15 Thumbdrive\DB\0014_TSf.ndf
```

From the result, the file '\SQL-Server\DATA\15 Thumbdrive\DB\0014_TSf.ndf' does have an id 15, not 14 as stated in the error message.

I tried to remove this file from the user database but couldn't because it's in "Recovery Pending" which means the database is not online at all.

I also tried to update sys.master_files or sys.sysbrickfile, but it didn't work, either, giving an error like "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed".

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Recovery pending means that for some reason SQL cannot run restart recovery on the database. Usually this is because the log is missing or corrupt.

If files exist and drive online then, try stopping and restarting the SQL service as it may be that SQL came up before the drive was available. That would have caused this error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and I did stop and restart the service many times but still not working. Any other thought? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Chek firs mdf and ldf is exist or not..
if exist run below coommand on master DB


ALTER DATABASE 'DATBASE NAME' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE 'DATBASE NAME' SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did what you suggested but it still didn't work. I finally gave up fixing the database and restored it using a backup from 2 months ago (the backup plan stopped working 2 months ago after a data file went wrong). Thank you again.